# How to Secure amazon s3 bucket web URL of a resource against unauthorised user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am totally new to s3 bucket, I know we can save images, videos, etc any kind of resources there.
when I want to access these images from my app I can access through web url but how to make sure any other unauthorised user can't see/download my image using that url(URL is so easy to guess if bucket name is known).

How to make the URL secure?

Can I use my preferred username & password into the URL to make it secure?

I also do not found any way to make the resources unaccessible through the URL that amazon uses(http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/resourcename.extension), is that possible?

Any help would be appreciated...
Thanks.

Comment: So you want each user to be able to access only his/her images and videos? Do you want to provide download links or display those medias on your app?

Comment: I want a secure url(like: http://www.s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname&username=harishPathak&password=ahjdgyFGT@n24435jkhjhfHJGUYKL675786897@) so that if any person knows my bucket name or bucket directory structure he can't access my bucket resources using that common url(http://www.s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/resourcename.extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make your bucket private.

Then, generate signed URL to access your content.

The format will be `https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/objectname?AWSAccessKeyId=<accesskey>&Expires=<expiretime>&Signature=<signature string>`

Please see https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

You can also try it with this tool: http://www.dancartoon.com/projects/s3-siggenerator/

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. Objects are private unless configured otherwise.  Bucket and object permissions/policies/acl are separate (but interacting) entities, and signed URLs that look like `AWSAccessKeyId=` (auth version 2) are only used in S3 regions initially launched before 2014.

Comment: Hi Michael, feel free to update this answer if you think it can be improved.

Comment: first, how can I make a bucket private(I tried through bucket explorer ACL), but the URL(https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/objectname) is still accessing the image.

second, If I use a signed URL, how can I fix the Expiration time(I am using URL to access resources in my app), or can I make that URL work forever(no time limit).

Comment: I created a new bucket and upload some objects into it, when I tried to access objects through URL in browser, it was inaccessible, It means bucket is private. Does it mean I am unable to make my current bucket private? If yes how to do so?
I am able to access that object from signed url but It will expire after given time, I also want that object to be accessible for lifetime. Is it possible?

Comment: Finally I got away with this.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Answer (score 0):

I am working for above task for security purpose how to get image and video from s3 bucket I found one npm module.

[aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)
I resolved my issue through asw-sdk solution.